# load file in lua

Tags: lua

I have directory that contain multiple file 
i need to load on specified file.

i know i can use loadfile(path) but how i need to specify which file to load
thank you 
Jp

Comment: In this context, the word "path" means "pathname of a file", not specifically "path to a file".

Comment: I am mixing `load` and `open`. Seems that `load` is for loading LUA script and `open` for file opening (e.g. for reading it): [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_file_io.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are asking, but here's my take on it.  If you know the directory you need to load the file from, you'd just prefix it to the name of the file:

```
local f, error = loadfile(mydir .. "/my_file")
```

Note that this reads and parses the file.  To actually execute it, you need to invoke the function you get back from `loadfile()` (so `f()` in this example).  If there is an error, `loadfile()` returns `nil` and an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "./path/to/a/file.lua"
local myreturn1, myreturn2 --[[etc]] = assert(loadfile(path))(myarg1, myarg2, myarg3 --[[etc]])
```